# 301 редирект Joomla. Error 500

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, redirect, http-status-code-500

Нашел в интернете данный код

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Вставил его после

```
RewriteEngine On
```

И на сайте ошибка 500 - Internal Server Error

Требовалось сделать редирект на домен сайта + слеш в конце

```
http://website.com -- http://website.com/
```